# Apache Flink: Kafka Producer in IDE execution not working as expected

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a sample streaming `WordCount` example written in Flink (Scala). In it, I want to put the result in Kafka using Flink-Kafka producer. But it is not working as expected.

My code is as follows:

```
object WordCount {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // set up the execution environment
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment
      .getExecutionEnvironment
      .setStateBackend(new RocksDBStateBackend("file:///path/to/checkpoint", true))

    // start a checkpoint every 1000 ms
    env.enableCheckpointing(1000)

    // set mode to exactly-once (this is the default)
    env.getCheckpointConfig.setCheckpointingMode(CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE)

    // make sure 500 ms of progress happen between checkpoints
    env.getCheckpointConfig.setMinPauseBetweenCheckpoints(500)

    // checkpoints have to complete within one minute, or are discarded
    env.getCheckpointConfig.setCheckpointTimeout(60000)

    // prevent the tasks from failing if an error happens in their checkpointing, the checkpoint will just be declined.
    env.getCheckpointConfig.setFailOnCheckpointingErrors(false)

    // allow only one checkpoint to be in progress at the same time
    env.getCheckpointConfig.setMaxConcurrentCheckpoints(1)

    // prepare Kafka consumer properties
    val kafkaConsumerProperties = new Properties
    kafkaConsumerProperties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181")
    kafkaConsumerProperties.setProperty("group.id", "flink")
    kafkaConsumerProperties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")

    // set up Kafka Consumer
    val kafkaConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer[String]("input", new SimpleStringSchema, kafkaConsumerProperties)

    println("Executing WordCount example.")

    // get text from Kafka
    val text = env.addSource(kafkaConsumer)

    val counts: DataStream[(String, Int)] = text
      // split up the lines in pairs (2-tuples) containing: (word,1)
      .flatMap(_.toLowerCase.split("\\W+"))
      .filter(_.nonEmpty)
      .map((_, 1))
      // group by the tuple field "0" and sum up tuple field "1"
      .keyBy(0)
      .mapWithState((in: (String, Int), count: Option[Int]) =>
        count match {
          case Some(c) => ((in._1, c), Some(c + in._2))
          case None => ((in._1, 1), Some(in._2 + 1))
        })

    // emit result
    println("Printing result to stdout.")
    counts.map(_.toString()).addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer[String]("output", new SimpleStringSchema,
      kafkaProperties))

    // execute program
    env.execute("Streaming WordCount")
  }
}
```

The data I sent to Kafka `input` topic is:

```
hi
hello
```

I don't get any output in Kafka topic `output`. Since I am a newbie to Apache Flink, I don't know how to achieve the expected result. Can anyone help me achieve the correct behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run your code into my local environment, and everything is OK. I think you can try the command below:

```
./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic  output --from-beginning
```